# QuickBooks SalesReceiptModRq XML invalid issue

Tags: php, xml, quickbooks

I'm trying to integrate Quickbooks API with our system - add user / modify user / add sale request are fine; the only request I've got problems with is the sale modification.

For the given XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="UK2.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesReceiptModRq requestID="25">
            <SalesReceiptMod>
                <ListID>80000003-1409581902</ListID>
                <EditSequence>1409583199</EditSequence>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <FullName>Support Team</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <RefNumber>00000017</RefNumber>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>2 House Number</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>House Street</Addr2>
                    <City>City</City>
                    <PostalCode>POST CODE</PostalCode>
                    <Country>GB</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <ShipAddress>
                    <Addr1>2 House Number</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>House Street</Addr2>
                    <City>City</City>
                    <PostalCode>POST CODE</PostalCode>
                    <Country>GB</Country>
                </ShipAddress>
                <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>Standard Sales</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Funtec Beach Line Festival Ball - &lt;p&gt;A good quality light and soft beach volleyball as used at Europes largest beach volleyball festival&lt;/p&gt;</Desc>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Rate>19.95</Rate>
                </SalesReceiptLineAdd></SalesReceiptMod>
        </SalesReceiptModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

the validator gives me error:

`Src Text: <SalesReceiptModRq requestID="25">
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.`

Of course it would be good if I had an access to DTD for QBXML. According to this DTD (http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd) my XML should be valid (SalesReceiptModRq with required requestID); though it's not correct one I hoped it would be similar enough to provide me with information on what is wrong.

So, dear SO - what's wrong with my XML and how can I make SalesReceiptModRq requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version of qbXML that is 11 years old and for QuickBooks UK 2003:

`<?qbxml version="UK2.0"?>`

The DTD you referred to is 8 years old and for QuickBooks USA 2007:

`qbxmlops60.dtd`

And you're not trying to modify `Invoices`, you're trying to modify `SalesReceipt`s:

`<SalesReceiptModRq`

You should use the [QuickBooks OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) as your reference. If you're trying to modify Invoices, then you need to look up `InvoiceModRq` for syntax.

Fix your qbXML version tag so that you're using the qbXML version that your QuickBooks actually supports (if it's a recent version of QuickBooks, try `9.0` or even `12.0`).

Comment: I'm using this `<?qbxml version="UK2.0"?>` as the validator doesn't validate the XML I'm generating (for the Web Connector) - it simply returns `The element 'QBXML' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema`, which is even weirder error. I thought that UK version meant exactly that - version that is up-to-date for UK market. Yes, I understand that the `qbxmlops60.dtd` is wrong; sadly it's the only one I was able to find when googling for qbxml dtd schemas. Sorry about that - yes, I meant to say that I'm adding / modifying sale receipts.

Comment: And finally - I'm actually using your devkit https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php (thanks for that!). Ah - one more thing: I'm in UK; I don't know if matters (I thought it did) as that's why I chose UK edition in validator

Comment: Thanks for the link https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html - this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Many years ago there were separate XML schemas for UK vs. US vs. CA. They are all the same now, so don't use "UK2.0" anymore. Instead use just "11.0" or something depending on what year of QuickBooks you're using. If you download the QuickBooks SDK, it contains the actual latest XSDs and an XML Validator tool that's helpful too.

Comment: I'm using the validator - unfortunately it didn't display what was wrong with my XML(I figured it out now though). Do you have by any chance updated version of PHP Development kit? (the examples from the linked one use the `<?qbxml version="2.0"?>`) - while I'm finished right now with my project, it might come handy if the client comes back with further requests.

Comment: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php   The examples are just examples. You should always be modifying them to suite your needs, and match your version of QuickBooks.

Comment: That's fine and dandy - now I know where to find the reference and that's is QBXML v13 (I searched for it though, couldn't find). I hoped though that you've got updated examples somewhere as well, mainly because the linked reference doesn't give any clue when to use `Rate` and when `Amount` (for Sale requests), and these two fields aren't the only ones that don't have any info about them. Validator gives me "OK", Web Connector gives me error, and I've no way to know why. Are there any resources you can provide to give insight how are the XMLs parsed and what data should they contain?

Comment: Download the QuickBooks SDK. There's 600 pages on topics like this. Additionally, the GUI almost exactly mirrors the XML. Familiarize yourself with the GUI. If you're getting errors, you have to actually post the error you're getting and the XML you're sending for anyone to be able to help you.